# When should we use redirect?

Tags: http, playframework-2.2

When should we give redirect status (30x) generally in HTTP Request?

Specifically in playframework, consider action `Application.index()` and `Application.login()`.

If the request routed to index and user has not logged in yet, it should go to login action. In `Application.index()`, should we use

```
if (!loggedIn())
  return redirect(Application.login())
```

or

```
if (!loggedIn())
  return Application.login()
```

?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on you, anyway keep in mind that login process requires more requests (I mean that after filling the form, user sends it, to action which will try to login him) so there's no sense to keep all these things in `index` action, So inn this case redirect will be just more comfortable solution.

Also keep in mind that search engine will *see* this redirect and won't consider your page as a common result.